# Is the concept of JFC and API in general, same?

Tags: java, api

I have this question, since what I understand from the definitions of JFC and APi are, they both are a set of Pre defined classes/ methods which can be used in the development of an application.

So, can we consider the context of both JFC and API same?

Comment: [JFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Foundation_Classes) is graphical framework for building guis. [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is set of classes for building software in general

Answer (score 1):

> The Java Foundation Classes (JFC) are a comprehensive set of GUI components and services
>   which dramatically simplify the development and deployment of
>   commercial-quality desktop and Internet/Intranet applications.
>
> application programming interface (API) is a set of routines,
>   protocols, and tools for building software applications. An API
>   expresses a software component in terms of its operations, inputs,
>   outputs, and underlying types.

JFC is specific for GUI in Java

API is a general concept to express software component